# Serving assets on two different ports

Tags: nginx, localhost

I have one PHP app running on localhost port 80 and another running on port 81.

Pointing the browser to `http://localhost` runs the first app and all of its assets: js, css, imgs in the `/assets` folder. However, the 2nd app only can serve assets that have the *exact* file name as the 1st app. If the 2nd app's assets are in the 2nd app's `/assets` directory and don't have the same name as files in the first apps `/assets` folder, then those files aren't found an you get a `404` error.

Here's more specifics on what I'm seeing:

**`http://localhost`**

```
<script src='/assets/foo.js'></script>
//file contents
alert('foo'); when foo.js is in app #1's /assets directory
```

**`http://localhost:81`**

```
<script src='/assets/foo.js'></script>

alert('foo 2'); //alerts "foo 2" when foo.js is in app #2's /assets directory

<script src='/assets/bar.js'></script>
//file contents:
alert('bar'); //file not found 404 error when bar.js is in app #2's /assets directory
```

The likely cause of the problem in my `nginx.conf`:

```
http {   
    include /Applications/MNPP/conf/nginx/sites-enabled/app2;
    include /Applications/MNPP/conf/nginx/sites-enabled/app1;
    ...
```

/Applications/MNPP/conf/nginx/sites-enabled/app2:

```
server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  localhost:81;
    ...
```

/Applications/MNPP/conf/nginx/sites-enabled/app1:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    ...
```

Comment: Please post your complete nginx configuration.

Comment: here's the nginx.conf: https://gist.github.com/tim-peterson/eb180321a079acc21355

Comment: And app1/app2 complete configuration too please?

Comment: here's the app2 config: https://gist.github.com/tim-peterson/ad2c1fae03f850ec7247

Comment: here's the app1 config: https://gist.github.com/tim-peterson/32a67466c7c8d52ceda6 (it's nearly identical to app2's config)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you are specifying `root` directive inside a `location` block. There should be no reason to use that inside `location`.

Try moving the contents of `location /` block to `server` level, and remove `location /` completely.

Also, you shouldn't need `location /assets` either, because with this specification it resolves to exactly same path when `root` is specified on `server` level.

Comment: Yes this worked!! thanks! now I understand nginx.conf better!!

Answer (score 1):

This will not match: `server_name  localhost:81;`

Change it to: `server_name  localhost;`

You can have the same "server name" on multiple ports. The listen block is enough for nginx to  tell which server block it should process.

Comment: That didn't fix the problem unfortunately. Is this a relative path issue? See my url's above: `'/assets/foo.js'`